# Laravel - Multi fields search form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

I'm builind a form with laravel to search users, this form has multiple fields like

1. Age (which is mandatory)
2. Hobbies (optional)
3. What the user likes (optional)
4. And some others to come

For the age, the user can select in the list (18+, 18-23,23-30, 30+ etc...) and my problem is that i would like to know how i can do to combine these fields into one single query that i return to the view.

For now, i have something like this :

```
        if(Input::get('like')){
        $users = User::where('gender', $user->interested_by)->has('interestedBy', Input::get('like'))->get();
        if(strlen(Input::get('age')) == 3){
            $input = substr(Input::get('age'),0, -1);
            if(Input::get('age') == '18+' || Input::get('age') == '30+' )
            {
                foreach ($users as $user)
                {
                    if($user->age($user->id) >= $input){
                        $result[] = $user;
                        // On enregistre les users étant supérieur au if plus haut
                    }
                    else
                        $result = [];
                }
                return view('search.result', ['users' => $result]);
            }
            elseif (strlen(Input::get('age')) == 5) {
            $min = substr(Input::get('age'), 0, -3);
            $max = substr(Input::get('age'), -2);
            $result = array();
            foreach($users as $user)
            {
                if($user->age($user->id) >= $min && $user->age($user->id) <= $max)
                    $result[] = $user;
            }
            return view('search.result', ['users' => $result]);
            }
    }
    else
        $users = User::all();
```

And so the problem is that there is gonna be 2 or 3 more optional fields coming and i would like to query for each input if empty but i don't know how to do it, i kept the age at the end because it's mandatory but i don't know if it's the good thing to do.
Actually this code works for now, but if i had an other field i don't know how i can do to query for each input, i know that i have to remove the get in my where and do it at the end but i wanna add the get for the last query..

Edit: my models :

User.php

```
 public function interestedBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\InterestedBy');
    }
```

And the same in InterestedBy.php

```
class InterestedBy extends Model{
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'interested_by';

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you can use query builer to do this as follow

```
$userBuilder = User::where(DB::raw('1')); //this will return builder object to continue with the optional things
// if User model object injected using ioc container $user->newQuery() will return blank builder object
$hobbies = Request::input('hobbies') // for laravel 5
if( !empty($hobbies) )
{
   $userBuilder = $userBuilder->whereIn('hobbies',$hobbies) //$hobbies is array
}
//other fields so on
$users = $userBuilder->get();
//filter by age

$age = Request::input('age');
$finalRows = $users->filter(function($q) use($age){
    return $q->age >= $age; //$q will be object of User
});

//$finalRows will hold the final collection which will have only ages test passed in the filter
```

Answer (score 1):

A way you could possible do this is using query scopes (more about that [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes)) and then check if the optional fields have inputs.

Here is an example

**Inside your User Model**

```
//Just a few simple examples to get the hang of it.

public function scopeSearchAge($query, $age)
{
   return $query->where('age', '=', $age);
  });
}

public function scopeSearchHobby($query, $hobby)
{
   return $query->hobby()->where('hobby', '=', $hobby);
  });
}
```

**Inside your Controller**

```
public function search()
{
  $queryBuilder = User::query();

  if (Input::has('age'))
  {
     $queryBuilder ->searchAge(Input::get('age'));
  }

  if (Input::has('hobby'))
  {
     $queryBuilder->searchHobby(Input::get('hobby'));
  }

  $users= $queryBuilder->get();
```

}

Comment: I like the idea of using scopes. But i would move the input check into the scope, so you can chain them like this: User::searchAge(Input::get("age")->searchHobby(Input::get(hobby)... and so on.

Comment: This is a viable solution too ofcourse , but for the sake of simplicity I just dumped my inputs in the controller. A better way to do this for a bigger application,in my opinion, is to provide an abstraction layer like a repository that implements an interface. But I think this example is enough to get one started.

Comment: Yeah this idea seems very well but i store the age as the date of birth, not directly the age and i calcul the age in my User.php so what is the best way to get the equivalent of what you've done for the age ? All the other tables ('hobbies', etc...) are many to many, so if what i think understand is correct,  instead of $query->where('hobby', '=', $hobby); i have to do $query->has('hobby', $hobby) that's it ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your mean, relationships are a separate thing from queries. Relationships just relate entities (models) to each other. We use queries to extract that information from our database. Calculating the age every time you do a search request might become a performance issue as your application grows. Instead create a column name age_cache in your DB and calculate the age once. Then search your db based on that value. You can also set up a cron task to update your age_cache fields every day,month or year.